# Where can I find a straight-forward tutorial on creating ActionScript 3.0 fading rollovers that assumes you know nothing about Flash? (CS5)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am a retoucher and when I post my pictures on my website I want visitors to be able to roll over the picture and have it fade to the original unretouched version and when they move the mouse away I want it to fade back to the retouched.

In my search I have found guides on deviant art for Actionscript 2.0 and for ActionScript 3.0 but the AS 3.0 one i found does not include the fade effect i want to achieve.  Google has also helped me find some tutorials but they are too advanced for me to understand.  If someone could show me where to find a beginner's tutorial using flash cs5 on this that would be great thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Question,

So you plan to use external images and have them dynamically loaded making it easy to change them at a later date or do you plan to have a swf with the images embedded?